# Registrer in array and new variable

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am trying to make a program where you can register expenses on someone.

i have 2 TextInputs, named "txt1" and "txt2"

I want to make an eventlistener where

If you put in a new name in “txt1”, it will be registered in an array, and a new variable will be created, and the number in “txt2” will be added to that variable.

If you put in a name that’s already in the array, the number in “txt2” will be added the variable which was created when you typed in the name the first time.

Here's what i got so far

```
var names:Array = new Array();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, regi)
function regi(evt)
 {
if (evt.keyCode == 13)
    {
        var k:String = txt1.text

        if (names.indexOf(k) != -1) 
        {
            txt1.text+txt2.text
        }
        else
        {
            names[names.length] = k
            var txt1.text = txt2.text
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use Dictionary to do that ex:

```
var names:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, regi);

function regi( evt:KeyboardEvent ):void
{
    if (evt.keyCode == 13)
    {   
        if( names[txt1.text] )  names[txt1.text] += txt2.text;
        else                    names[txt1.text] = txt2.text;
    }
}
```